# How to get form-control to extend across fieldset?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a hard time figuring out how to figure out how to make my contact form-control match the edge of my Work form-control. I'm still new with Bootstrap and not sure what I am doing wrong or how to fix the issue. I need my Contact and Email form-control to go all the way to the edge of my Work form-control.

Here is a screen to better explain. As you can see my layout is off in the Contact fieldset
[image: Explanation]

Here is my markup

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add Customer</legend>
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="container col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtCustomer" class="control-label col-md-2">Customer</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input id="txtCustomer" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtAddress1" class="control-label col-md-2">Address</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input id="txtAddress1" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtAddress2" class="control-label col-md-2">Address2</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input id="txtAddress2" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtCity" class="control-label col-md-2">City</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input id="txtCity" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtState" class="control-label col-md-2">State</label>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input id="txtState" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <label for="txtZip" class="control-label col-md-2">Zip/Postal</label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input id="txtZip" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="container col-md-12">
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Contact</legend>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtContactName" class="control-label col-md-2">Contact</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10 RemovingPadding">
                            <input id="txtContactName" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtEmail" class="control-label col-md-2">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input id="txtEmail" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtPhone" class="control-label col-md-2">Phone</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input id="txtPhone" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <label for="txtWork" class="control-label col-md-2">Work</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input id="txtWork" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtMobile" class="control-label col-md-2">Mobile</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input id="txtMobile" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <label for="txtFax" class="control-label col-md-2">Fax</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input id="txtFax" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtOther" class="control-label col-md-2">Other</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input id="txtOther" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <label for="txtOther2" class="control-label col-md-2">Other 2</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input id="txtOther2" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtOther3" class="control-label col-md-2">Other 3</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input id="txtOther3" type="text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want your output like in the screenshot?

Comment: @ManojKumar, no. The markup that I provided gives me that result. I need to have the Contact textbox to match the end of the Work textbox, same with the Email textbox.

Comment: But it shows full width for me here.

Comment: @ManojKumar, Really? because I am getting what you see in the picture..I forgot to mention this is in an MVC project.

Comment: Check this: http://prntscr.com/7da950 MVC or not, it depends on the CSS.

Comment: @ManojKumar, I'm going to have to go digging around in the CSS files. Hopefully I can find where this issue lays, I didn't create the project.

Comment: do you have a live link to the site so we can see your other css that may be affecting the layout?